# How to calculate this likelihood function question?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

We have $$f(t | \theta)= \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{t}{\theta}}$$

And we're asked to find out the likelihood function for $\theta$, $t \geq 0$

My thoughts are:

We use the usual process of $\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(t_i|\theta) $ but sometimes you have to add an indicator variable like $I(t_i > \theta)$ of some sort. Is this a case where we do so? And if so what would it be?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use an indicator to indicate the support of the random variable. This means that your pdf does not actually look like that per se, but it should be
$$f(t|\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-t/\theta} 1_{[0, \infty)}(t).$$
You can fill this into the usual way of calculating the likelihood.

Note that in this case, this is not so interesting, because the support does not depend on $\theta$. If the support does depend on $\theta$, this can become important.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to say at the outset that $$ f(t\mid\theta) = \frac1\theta e^{-t/\theta} \text{ for } t>0. \tag 1 $$

Then you have
$$
L(\theta) = \frac1 {\theta^n} e^{-(t_1+\cdots+t_n)/\theta} \text{ for } \theta\ge0. \tag 2
$$
Line $(1)$ above is valid only for $t_1,\ldots,t_n>0.$

Note that I wrote $\text{“}{>}\text{”}$ on line $(1)$ but $\text{“}{\ge}\text{”}$ on line $(2),$ because probability density functions are not defined pointwise, but likelihood functions are.